# nginx controller in k8 TLS version issue

Tags: kubernetes, curl, nginx-ingress, cert-manager

I have installed a nginx controller using the following link:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nginx-ingress-with-cert-manager-on-digitalocean-kubernetes

And I have added a NLB with TLS termination. Everything works as expected and I can ping the NLB domain but when I ping my domain with https although all the cert-manager settings are correct I receive the following error:

```
lij43@NCATS-2170711-M ~ % curl -v -I https://nginx-ing-poc.ncats.io/
*   Trying 52.72.56.47:443...
* Connected to nginx-ing-poc.ncats.io (52.72.56.47) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* (304) (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) error:1404B42E:SSL routines:ST_CONNECT:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

I expect to see the output as echo1 which is mentioned id DO's instructions.